# Match at least one letter, one number and one non-alphanum

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to make a password validator. It only allows passwords with at least one letter, at least one number and at least one non-alphanumeric character.

I have the below which works:

```
function passwordValidate(password, password_c, msg)
{
    if (notEmpty(password, "Enter a password"))
    {
        if (password.value === password_c.value)
        {
            if(/\W/.test(password.value))
            {
                if (/\d/.test(password.value) && /[a-zA-Z]/.test(password.value))
                {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            } else {
                alert("Must have a special character in your password");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Passwords don't match");
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I initially had "`password.value.match("\W|_")`" which was causing a problem so changed it to "`/\W/.test(password.value)`". Does anyone know how I can combine this into one regular expression?

Comment: [Why are you duplicating someone else's questions from a different forum??](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?273367-Need-to-match-at-least-one-letter-at-least-one-number-and-at-least-one-non-alphanum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use assertions.
The assertions sub-pattern is matched in the regular manner except that it doesnt cause the current matching position to be changed.

Try:

```
var rgx=/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^0-9a-zA-Z])/

//my test
var theTest=['azert7ui@i4','uiou5','4761238|z','jhkj','8989go','457@457'];
for (i=0;i<theTest.length;i++) alert(theTest[i]+' '+rgx.test(theTest[i]));
```

So initially we test 1 digit (`?=.*\d`) . It can be preceded with something or not.
Next is alphabetic characters and non-alphabetic characters. The use of `\w` ("word" character is any letter or digit) which duplicate digit is wrong (test is true with only digits and special characters).
The `\` is a special meaning in a string so the test is wrong.

Hope that helps

Comment: [And why are you copying someone else's answer to this question from the same forum the question was copied from??](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?273367-Need-to-match-at-least-one-letter-at-least-one-number-and-at-least-one-non-alphanum) Very strange!!

Answer (score 1):

Also, instead of making these nested staircases of `if` statements, break out early. It's much cleaner:

```
function passwordValidate(password, password_c, msg) {
    if (!notEmpty(password, "Enter a password")) {
        return false;
    }

    if (password.value !== password_c.value) {
        alert("Passwords don't match");
        return false;
    }

    if(!/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z])/.test(password.value)) {
        alert("Must have a special character in your password");
        return false;
    }

    alert(msg);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It might not be the lack of a special character that causes the fail.

Answer (score 0):

// It may be easier to do separate tests-

```
function testPassword(pw){
    pw= pw.replace(/\s+/, ''); //remove spaces
    var msg= [' non-alphanumerical', ' alphabetical', ' digit'],
    rx= [/\W/,/[a-zA-Z]/,/\d/];
    for(var i= 0;i<3;i++){
        if(!rx[i].test(pw)) throw Error('At least one'+
        msg[i]+' character is required');
    }
    return pw;
}
```